# Перевод статистика проверяющего

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Добрый день не переведена статистика проверяющего :

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/74433

> Статистика проверяющего
>
> ```
> Krom Stern has approved 243 edit suggestions and rejected 65 edit suggestions and improved 52 edit suggestions
> Vartlok has approved 73 edit suggestions and rejected 12 edit suggestions and improved 1 edit suggestions
> ```

Comment: Хм, когда-то мы это переводили с жаркими спорами. Слетел перевод, похоже.